# OAuth Authorization access, how to get Authorisation page on REST client tools like Postman?I am seeing HTML content

Tags: integration, oauth2

I am using **Postman client** for testing salesforce REST Services, but i am confused on how to get the Authorization page in the client. I am using the User agent flow and passing in the values and i am getting a HTML response but not the pop up for authorization where i can proceed, can we get the authorisation page in REST clients and is there any setting needed for this.

Attaching a screenshot which shows the HTML content which contains the Authorisation page, is there anything i am doing wrong?[image]

*Since i am using a vanilla DE version i am not blanking out the client ID*

I do see the Authorise screen on using the OOTB OAuth mechanism in Postman, that makes me think if i can see the Authorisation when i pass the OAuth parameters in the body manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well any Oath flow you consider will only provide you HTML code with some javascript code that will redirect you to Salesforce/or any service authorization page.

The oauth flow you chose is webserver/UA which implies your server/client has GUI and can handle HTML redirect and hence normally you wont face any issue while implementing it at your end.

Here Postman is basically a request response analysis tool. And it does not redirect you to the endpoint provided.

Copy/pasting the url provided in HTML response in your normal browser will still allow you to get Authorised. But yay When you implement it fully you wont need any manual intervention then.

Comment: I do the see the Authorization screen when implementing OOTB postman OAuth, that made me think that i am missing something so that HTML page is rendered by my Client (Postman). Updated the screenshot in my question.

Comment: So what is the way to test the Authorization from a client, i need to implement it? i am sure there must be a way to 'authorize' and 'test' your OAuth before you start implementation. Is there any other tool where i can do this?

Comment: What kind of client you have? Desktop App,Android App? You wanna implement its any specific language? Cause standalone postman wont help much.

Comment: SFDCFOX has elaborated how to use this using a java webapp.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BYUIA2

Comment: I want to implement a user agent flow and before starting to build the client, i want to test this flow in any testing tool, looks like that is going to be a challenge because of the Authorization page?

Comment: Nah it won't be a challenge. Authorization page is HTMl. Every client can handle HTML.  I haven't done same with SF but did smething similar on Dropbox(which uses  Oath2 as well) using Java. You can follow below. link.
http://javapapers.com/java/dropbox-java-api-tutorial/

Comment: There is no way to parse the html to set pm.variable? I can run test to verify there is a code with `pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("code=");` but next I was hoping to `pm.variables.set("authorization_code", parsed_var)`. Is this really not possible with example markup from OP?

Answer (score 0):

Postman is for only handling the http requests and responses. This cannot be done.